# Is 'for your health' a correct response in the context of showering?

Tags: idioms, spoken-english

Please is "for your health" a correct answer in the following context?

Speaker A: I'll take a shower or I've just taken a shower.

Speaker B: For your health.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean a response in the sense that we say "bless you" after someone sneezes?

Comment: Around my house the usual response is "*Please* hang up the towels."

Comment: #Stoney thanks for the funny response, but could please be precise? I mean is it wrong or correct?

Comment: This concept is very foreign to me as a native English speaker. I've never been aware that this was common in some cultures.

Comment: The phrase _for your health_ sounds like an awkward toast or something. I can't imagining using it as a response to someone who has just taken a shower, brushed their teeth, or taken a vitamin.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard response to phrases about taking or having taken a shower in English.

If my husband told me "I'm going to take a shower", my response would be something along the lines of:

> Enjoy!
>   Hurry, I need to take one too.
>   Don't use up all the hot water!

There's no "set phrase" for this.

If I was out with a friend and they told me "I've just taken a shower", I'd wonder by they had bothered to tell me, unless they were explaining why their hair is wet. My response would likely be confusion and a blank stare.

Outside of family and close friends, people don't generally discuss their showering plans.